# Check the presence of loop in a path on 2D plane

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am given `n` points on a `2D plane` which are joined by line segments to form a single path starting at first point and ending at `n^th` point. I need to check if a loop exists anywhere in the path. I can solve this in `O(nlogn)` using [this algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-set-of-line-segments-find-if-any-two-segments-intersect/) to check for crossing of disjoint line segments. What is the better approach considering that all line segments connect to form a single path?

Comment: i think you confused "contains a loop" with "is self intersecting". Apart from that there are plenty of algorithms out there for this problem, so i won't list any of them here, most of the algorithms suited to solve your problem can aswell be used to check a polygon for self-intersection and vice versa